# How to make a module contribution

Tags: community-official-site

I find some bugs in a contrib module I have fixed them and I want to commit my change to that module ,what is the right procedure to do that .

I did this is that ok.

1. create a new drupal site instlation.
2. cd to the module folder then clone the module git inside it (following the Version control instruction page)
3. I have fixed the problem , then commit and push to the git repo.

the problem with this method is that I can't explain the problem in detail with a just a commit so should I open a module issue in drupal website and link it to my commit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until pull requests on https://git.drupalcode.org become a thing the procedure still is basically as follows:

1. Create an issue in that module's issue queue on drupal.org.
2. Git clone that module's repo and checkout the branch where you wanna fix something.
3. Fix the bug.
4. Create a patch: `$ git diff > [project_name]-[short-description]-[issue-number]-[comment-number].patch`
5. Upload that patch in the issue from step 1. and set the issue to "Ready for review".

Now everybody finding the same bug can apply that patch at best using Composer and maybe [`cweagans/composer-patches`](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) until the patch got committed and released by one of the module's maintainers.

The full documentation can be found on drupal.org:

- [Making a Drupal patch with Git](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484)
- [Advanced patch contributor guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1054616).

Comment: It may also be helpful to link to https://www.drupal.org/community/#contribute-code and https://www.drupal.org/contribute/development